# Calling javascript method from java does not work with Chrome and Safari

Tags: java, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, gwt

I am trying to run JS function from Java using google gwt Frame as shown :

```
frame.setUrl("javascript:foo('jack!');void(0);");
```

Then the iframe automaticaly changes src attribute to be as shown :

```
<iframe class="gwt-Frame" src="javascript:foo('jack!');void(0);">
 <html>
  // html page contain foo method and other styles 
 </html>
</iframe>
```

What happens is that after the function is executed the iframe reset itself with an empty html document in Chrome and Safari but it works fine in FireFox.

I noticed that those lines are triggered in Jquery just before the document is reset :

```
// Used for iframes
// See setDocument()
// Removing the function wrapper causes a "Permission Denied"
// error in IE
unloadHandler = function() {
    setDocument();
},
```

Can you help ?